# Creating reusable array definitions in swagger

Tags: arrays, yaml, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm working on a definition/documentation-first specification of an API using Swagger 2.0. I've managed to break-out most reusable components into a definitions section however I am having trouble figuring out how to create reusable definitions for arrays of constants.

For example, I have a few paths that will return images, like this one:

```
paths:
  /resource/{imageId}:
    get:
      produces:
        - image/jpeg
        - image/png
        - image/gif
      parameters: 
        - in: path
          name: imageId
          type: string
          required: true
      responses: 
        200:
          description: Success
          schema:
            type: file
```

Which works just fine, but I would like to be able to define a reusable array of the values for the "produces" element so that I can reuse the same list for any path that will produce an image.

The following seemed like the intuitive approach, but swagger reports that the definition for imageMimeTypes is not valid:

```
paths:
  /resource/{imageId}:
    get:
      produces:
        $ref: "#/definitions/imageMimeTypes"
      parameters: 
        - in: path
          name: imageId
          type: string
          required: true
      responses: 
        200:
          description: Success
          schema:
            type: file
definitions:
  imageMimeTypes:
    - image/jpeg
    - image/png
    - image/gif
```

Is it possible to create a definition for an array like this? If so, what syntax should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if these `produces` values are used in *most* operations, you can define them as global `produces` and override where needed.

```
produces:
  - image/jpeg
  - image/png
  - image/gif

paths:
  /resource/{imageId}:
    get:
      # Inherits global "produces"
      ...
  /something:
    get:
      # Overrides global "produces"
      produces:
        - application/json
      ...
```

Your second example is not valid, because `produces` cannot have a `$ref` value. But you can use YAML anchors to achieve a similar effect. Note that an anchor must be defined before it is used, so you need to put the list above the path definition.

```
x-types:
  imageMimeTypes: &IMAGE-MIME-TYPES
    - image/jpeg
    - image/png
    - image/gif

paths:
  /resource/{imageId}:
    get:
      produces: *IMAGE-MIME-TYPES
      parameters: 
        - in: path
          name: imageId
          type: string
          required: true
      responses: 
        200:
          description: Success
          schema:
            type: file
```

I put the list under an extension key `x-types` instead of `definitions` 1) because [`definitions`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#definitionsObject) is intended for input and output models and not random lists, and 2) to prevent the "unused definition" warning in the Swagger Editor.

This works in (at least) Swagger Editor and Swagger UI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Helen.  It looks like using YAML anchors will work well for our purposes.

Regarding specifying a global `produces` definition, I should have mentioned that I'm already specifying application/json as my global value for `produces` since that is what most of my API will be producing, but I will have a few paths, like this one, that will return images.

Comment: Also, thank you for pointing out that these should be defined in x-types rather than definitions.